# Unable to customize tool bar in Safari compact tab layout

Tags: safari

I wanted to try out the compact tab layout that Safari offers and wanted to customize the toolbar. I right clicked and selected `customize toolbar` and the little widgets started to wiggle, but the normal menu with options didn't pop up like this..
[image]

I went to switch back to the regular tab layout and accidentally removed the address field from the toolbar.. I tried everything from clearing caches and website data to rebooting my Mac and deleting the .plist for safari..
Any idea how I can restore the toolbar to default if the customize toolbar menu is broken?

Comment: Have you looked in *View > Customise Toolbar* (in the menu bar)?

Comment: @Thinkr facing the same issue, and summoning it through the View button in the menu bar doesn't work either. The few remaining toolbar icons still just wiggle. How is this three grand machine buggier than my $600 Windows laptop...

Comment: @gargoylebident Wait, so you mean you can't get the menu to show up when using the regular layout? I cannot manage to replicate the issue here.

Comment: @Thinkr correct, at some point all buttons but one were gone, including all tabs. The sidebar still worked for tab navigation though. Switching to traditional tabs didn't fix anything, just added an empty bar at the top of the window. Rebooting didn't help. Uninstalling the two extensions I have (both from the App Store) and closing and reopening Safari something like 10 times somehow fixed the issue for now. This is a fresh macOS install, I don't have a single third party program. Only things I've changed are System Settings.

Comment: @gargoylebident Well glad it got fixed. It'll be good to try to diagnose the issue to avoid it happening again.